# Mis-arranged dictionary pairs when host on Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, flask

When I print the dictionary in the interpreter, it works as desired, but when I use it as Flask API return value the dictionary becomes a mess, all key-value pairs are mis-organized.

- Not desired JSON data (got this on Flask API) - https://pastebin.com/jrfLMVNg
- Desired JSON data (got this on interpreter) - https://pastebin.com/cDJnah07

Probably the faulty code:

```
def dataPacker(self,*datas):
    for data in datas:
        if type(data) == dict:
            for key,value in data.items():
                self.returnDataJson[key] = value
        else:   
            raise Exception('dict object expected')

def dataCollector(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            details_ = executor.submit(self.dataPacker,self.details)
            audiolink_ = executor.submit(self.dataPacker,self.audiolink)
            videolink_ = executor.submit(self.dataPacker,self.videolink)
            lyrics_ = executor.submit(self.dataPacker,self.lyrics)
        
        return self.returnDataJson
```

Is this because of threading? But why does it work fine on Interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the items in the wrong order, but each key has the right value?

- You don't say which version of Python this is; older versions didn't keep items in order (it was arbitrary), and Flask may be deliberately making it random as well as arbitrary in order to protect against attacks.
- If it comes to that, the order of items in a JSON dictionary (object) is defined to be unimportant, so you shouldn't rely on it if you can at all help it.
- Threading will indeed make the order potentially interleaved. If you need to rely on the order, you'll need to put in some mechanism to guarantee it; currently it's just chance whether it ends up in the order you want or in some other order.

Comment: Check my answer I found a way.

Comment: OK, but (a) threading making things potentially interleaved is still going to be a problem, perhaps depending on load or other factors; and (b) if the other end is depending on item order, it's doing JSON wrong, potentially leading to problems further down the track.

Answer (score 0):

I found Cliff Kerr's Answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528529/maintain-order-when-dumping-dict-to-json)
helpful. I just added `app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False` to my code and now it doesn't sort it alphabetically and keeps the dict ordered.